# Update A ListView In One Fragment From A Second Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a `ViewPager` that shows the user 2 fragments.

- Fragment 1 contains a button with an `onClickListener` that adds an entry to the `ListView` contents in fragment 2. The new entry is a number generated by a random number generator.
- Fragment 2 contains a `ListView` with some random numbers in.

I cannot find a way to refresh the list in fragment 2 from the button listener in fragment 1. **How do i do this?**

I have tried:

1. initializing and setting the list adapter in an `onResume` in
   fragment 2.
2. Calling `myViewPager.notifyDataSetChanged` from fragment 1.

Neither of the above methods have worked. Any ideas?

---

Edit: Here is my code:

**layout_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

**layout_frag_one.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/main_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Add Number" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**layout_frag_two**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class SlideActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private final static int FRAGMENT_NUMBER = 2;
    private ViewPager pager;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainpager);
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.mainpager);
    pager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    private class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        }

        public Fragment getItem(int index) {
            switch(index){
            case 0:
                 return new Fragment1();
            case 1:
                 return new Fragment2();
             default:
                 return new Fragment1();
            }
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return FRAGMENT_NUMBER;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to implement some of this to get it working right:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

And some more reading here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity